# Pythons Bottle with SQLITE3

Tags: python, sqlite, bottle

I have been trying to practise Bottle Py. There is a tutorial about making an APP: TODO.

It works fine. But If task id exceeds 1 character that means 10 instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

It shows error like below.

> ProgrammingError('Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current
>   statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.',)

[image]

Code is:

```
@route('/edit/<no:int>', method='GET')
def edit_item(no):

    if request.GET.save:
        edit = request.GET.task.strip()
        status = request.GET.status.strip()

        if status == 'open':
            status = 1
        else:
            status = 0

        conn = sqlite3.connect('todo.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("UPDATE todo SET task = ?, status = ? WHERE id LIKE ?", (edit, status, no))
        conn.commit()

        return '<p>The item number %s was successfully updated</p>' % no
    else:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('todo.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT task FROM todo WHERE id LIKE ?", (str(no)))
        cur_data = c.fetchone()

        return template('edit_task', old=cur_data, no=no)
```

Tracebacks:

1.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1737, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "todo.py", line 67, in edit_item
    c.execute('SELECT task FROM todo WHERE id LIKE ?', no)
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

**2.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1737, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "todo.py", line 67, in edit_item
    c.execute('SELECT task FROM todo WHERE id LIKE ?', (no))
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might happen because the `execute` function will unpack your second parameter when you do `(str(no))` the outer `()` will not convert your tuple, you need to do `(str(no),)` if you have only one element in the tuple.

For instance, since it recognized as string, it will unpack `"10"` it into `("1", "0")`

Comment: Try to pass a list instead of tuple or just pass the `no` itself

Comment: Can you add the new traceback to your question?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: @FahadAhammed in your trackbacks I don't see the `(no,)` or `(str(no),)`

Comment: Oh yeah got it !!!

c.execute("SELECT task FROM todo WHERE id LIKE ?", (no,))

Thanks man ! :)